# how to install filezilla on CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos6

I downloaded `FILEZILLA` from https://filezilla-project.org/download.php.Now how to install this on CentOs,please suggest me.

Answer (score 12):

For Cent OS 7

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum -y install filezilla
```

Go to **Application > Internet > Filezilla**

Comment: @NitishKumarPal `Answer "yes" to every question in the transaction.`
https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-yum-common-options.html

Answer (score 5):

You need to first download and install epel-release package from here..
http://fedora.mirrors.pair.com/epel/6/i386/repoview/epel-release.html

then you can install by typing **yum install filezilla**

Thanks..

Comment: Link broken or moved

Answer (score 3):

100% working solution is here:

the question is very old.. but i m posting answer so that anyone else struggling to install `fileZilla` on `centOS 6 or 5` may get help.

this works for me on `centOS6.5` goto below link and follow the instruction:

note before following the instruction run this command on terminal:

`su`

`sudo -i`

`cd /tmp`

now follow the instruction from below link.

http://www.servermom.org/2-cents-tip-how-to-enable-epel-repo-on-centos-6-and-5/894/

then install `filezilla` like this:

`yum install filezilla`

and you done.

to start `fileZilla` goto `Applications->Internet->FileZilla`